why does this LM393 need too much voltage to go high
I have the following circuit taken from Arts of Electronics. I am using it to detect zero-crossing of a 40V-RMS/50Hz input. I am connecting the output of the comparator LM 393 to a GPIO pin of  Raspi pico W, therefor the R7 resembles a pull-up resistor to the 3.3V V2, the same as in the Pi. I have changed R4, R5, R6, and R7 values for different hysteresis. I have used the formulas written in the answers of this post for calculation.

The simulation looks promising and gave results close to what I was expecting:

However, when building this circuit IRL, I was very confused (CH1 is the input signal and CH2 is between the Comp output and ground):

It requires approximately 10V for the comparator to go high and 0.325V to go low. What confuses me is that when I change the oscilloscope's scale from 5V/div to 2V/div, the yellow signal jumps by 2 divisions. I then need to add an offset to move the input signal back to the point where the comparator goes high. I am changing the scale to get more precise readings, but while it looks normal at 5V/div, this issue occurs at 2V/div.
Am I missing something? I've checked the soldering, and components, and tried different probes, but I'm still not making any progress.
EDIT:
Here is the same measurement with a scale of 2.1V/div looking close to the simulation. Note that when I change the scale from anything to 2V/div I hear a clicking sound from the Osciliscope:

and here is the measurement between the inverting input and ground:



Some GPIO pins on the RPi have external resistors installed on the board.  Are you sure you aren't fighting that?

i dont know actually @Aaron. how to be sure?

Have you constructed the circuit exactly matching the simulate circuit? It looks like you haven't.

@KevinWhite I have double-checked it and everything seems to be exactly like the simulated circuit.

Post the oscillograms for both scales. Right now, you are just posting the 2V/div in both images.

Show the actual input to the comparator (at C2).

@MOSFET. I have added the requested oscillograms.

Again, your vertical scale is all the same. You are changing time (the horizontal scale). Update your post as it is not clear if your issue is with the amplitude (vertical 2V/div) or the time (5ms/div).

A common trap in microcontrollers in general - sometimes, when a pin is set to input or high-impedance mode, the pin can still create an output signal but with a high impedance. I once wasted a day trying to figure out why my logic circuit was unresponsive. Probably not your problem, but useful to be mindful of that.

What are the three traces? It is not obvious. Have you checked the value of the resistors with  meter - maybe you are reading them incorrectly. If I am interpreting the traces correctly it looks like it is working.

The duty cycle of the comparator output is 50 %, so your circuit is working properly. If it would trigger at 10 V, you would see another duty cyle. Are you saturating the scope input?

@Jens i dont know. what does saturating the scope input mean?

Some Y amplifier inside a skope don't behave well if the input amplitude is too high. You configured 2V/div but the signal input is 113 Vpp.

@mhdAwskamel - Thanks for clarifying your answer (confirming the comment by Jens). I have removed my earlier comment about that. || Although not mandatory, it is encouraged to upvote useful answers (when you have the points to do so) & to consider áccepting the "best" answer (using your judgement of "best") as that is how to indicate if the question has been solved. (Also see here.) TY


Some Y amplifiers inside a scope don't behave well if the input amplitude is too high. You configured 2V/div but the signal input is 113 Vpp.

The above comment posted by Jens on this question identified the issue.
(Copied with minor corrections, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license.)
